# Is minor leaking at bottom corners of exterior doors normal or acceptable?

Tags: doors, leak

I worked with a contractor who installed 2 French Doors and one "normal" door. All of them leak at the bottom corners. 2 of them are minor, but if I put a paper towel in the corner when it rains, it comes back wet. One of the doors is completely covered, and the other has partial cover. There is no standing water.

I haven't paid a lot of attention to exterior doors before, so my first question is:

Is this is normal and within acceptable limits of water incursion?

The french doors on the 2nd floor leak quite a bit, flooring wood rot is apparent in the left corner, and I've seen water stream in at the middle seam between the two doors. That's obviously not right. I'm trying to address this with the contractor now but trying to get some feedback.

If the leaks affect all doors, including one that is not a french door, wouldn't that indicate there's probably a problem with the contractor and not necessarily the doors?

They had door techs out from the manufacturer, we already replaced one of the french doors once (on the first floor), and I feel like we're going around in circles. They warranty their work but if they can't seem to actually do it right, then it seems like my only options are to try to fix it myself or to pay for a new contractor to give it a shot.

Thoughts?

Comment: Whether it's "normal" or not, it's not correct.  That said, I have a couple of exterior doors that do the same thing, so you're not alone.  I have not been able to chase the root cause of the leak down, but I think it's because the metal bottom sill of the door jamb slopes the wrong way, or doesn't slope enough towards the outside.

Comment: Really need a picture that shows the overall door and closeups of the leaks.

Comment: I just inserted a link to some videos.

Comment: Is there standing water outside the doors when it rains?   If so, that is the problem.  Those aren't submarine doors.

Comment: No standing water. One of those doors is under a covered awning with its own drainage, and even a drainage system right outside the door. It's kind of a mystery to me how water is even getting to that door, much less getting into those corners. I can only infer it's some wild wicking.

Comment: Sounds like maybe a trickle-down leak from higher up, at least for the door under the awning.

Comment: Doors have architectural ratings for weather resistance. Typically unless specified, home-center doors are lowest rating and should not expect to be completely watertight in adverse conditions. Higher rating means more $$, and none work right if not installed properly.

Comment: no way to answer this without pictures